# How to show a fixed number of characters from a sentence - symfony

Tags: symfony-1.4

I have a sentece that works like a title, but is to big to be shown in the page. I can I set the variable to only show a bit of the sentence in symfony?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [TextHelper](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/TextHelper). (`use_helper('Text');`) It has some nice functions like `truncate_text()`.

You can use it like this (in your View):

```
<?php use_helper('Text'); ?>
...
<?php echo truncate_text($text, 50); ?>
```

(The optional third parameter specifies which text you want to add when the text is being truncated (defaults to '...'). The optional boolean fourth parameter specifies wether you want to break on spaces explicitly. (and not somewhere in the middle of a word).

Comment: do you know how to use it? is it:
`use_helper('Text');
truncate_text(blablabla, 10, ..., false);` ?